# import dataset into google colab from another drive account

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

lastly I'm working on google colab 
I get this dataset colled celeba and it is into a google drive accout and this account is not mine but I have the access to go through it 
now because the internet problems and drive capacity I can not dounload the dataset then upload it to my drive ... so the question is: is there any way to let google colab get access to this dataset or such a way to import the path...

I have this function definition below

```
create_celebahq_cond_continuous('/content/drive/My Drive/kiki96/results/tfrecords','https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7EVK8r0v71pWEZsZE9oNnFzTm8','https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qLcYyJmiz0TXY1NG02bzZVRGs',4,100,False)
```

where I have tried to put the sharablelink of the dataset but, it does not work

please help

Comment: try this https://github.com/jibikbam/Download-from-Google-Drive-with-WGET-command-line/blob/master/download-celeba-dataset-from-google-drive.sh

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### To download a file to Colab

If you want to download the file directly into your Google Colab instance, then you can use `gdown`.

Note that the file must be shared to the public.

If the link to your dataset is `https://drive.google.com/file/d/10vAwF6hFUjvw3pf6MmB_S0jZm9CLWbSx/view?usp=sharing`, you can use:

```
!gdown --id "10vAwF6hFUjvw3pf6MmB_S0jZm9CLWbSx"
```

### To download the file to your Drive

Instead, if you want to download it to your drive then

Mount your Google Drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Change the directory to a folder in your Google Drive

```
cd '/content/drive/My Drive/datasets/'
```

Download the file into your Google Drive folder

```
!gdown --id "10vAwF6hFUjvw3pf6MmB_S0jZm9CLWbSx"
```

### To download a folder

If you are trying to download a folder, follow these steps:

1. Open the shared folder

[image: Shared Folder]

2. Click "Add shortcut to my drive" and select a folder

[image: Adding to drive]

3. Mount your Google Drive to Google Colab
4. Go to the folder where you added the shortcut

[image: Access to shared folder]

You can see the newly-added folder, being referenced by its Google Drive folder ID.

Comment: thanks for the kind replay, I have tried it but it gives an error "Maybe you need to change permission over 'Anyone with the link'?"

even when I am trying to get a shareable link from my drive

Comment: thanks man again, I just realize that the link is not shareable, still your replay very helpful

Comment: Just tried a new way to directly access shared folders and it worked! Cheers. Let me know if that worked for you too.

Comment: So simple, so clean! There are answers with 100 lines of code which does not even work.. here: !gdown "link"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the script here to download the whole folder.

https://github.com/segnolin/google-drive-folder-downloader

I've made it into an easy function.

```py
def folder_download(folder_id):
  # authenticate
  from google.colab import auth
  auth.authenticate_user()
  # get folder_name
  from googleapiclient.discovery import build
  service = build('drive', 'v3')
  folder_name = service.files().get(fileId=folder_id).execute()['name']
  # import library and download
  !wget -qnc https://github.com/segnolin/google-drive-folder-downloader/raw/master/download.py
  from download import download_folder
  download_folder(service, folder_id, './', folder_name)
  return folder_name
```

You can simply call it with the folder_id.

```
folder_download('0B7EVK8r0v71pWEZsZE9oNnFzTm8')
```

And it will create that folder in Colab.

Comment: thx for replaying, so this script will helps me download a folder from another drive account directly to my drive without downloading it to my machine

Comment: I have made it into an easy-to-use function.